How to prevent soft keyboard from closing when switching focus from TextField to EditText in Jetpack Compose
I'm working in a legacy codebase which uses EditText and I'm trying to introduce compose into our application. While playing around with the AndroidView(...) composable I noticed that the soft keyboard is closed when switching from a native TextField composable to a legacy EditText wrapped inside an AndroidView composable. Instead, I would expect the soft keyboard to remain visible as focus transfers between the two text fields.
Take the following compose code snippet for example. If you initially click the TextField and then click the EditText the soft keyboard closes. However, if you instead initially select the EditText and then select the TextField the soft keyboard will remain open as expected.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            KeyboardFocusSandboxTheme {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentSize()
                ) {
                    TextField(
                        value = "TextField",
                        onValueChange = {}
                    )
                    AndroidView(
                        factory = {
                            val v = EditText(it)
                            v.setText("EditText")

                            v
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried using both the FocusManager and LocalSoftwareKeyboardController with Modifiers to force request/free focus as well as force the soft keyboard to appear. Unfortunately nothing seems to be working and I'm not sure what else is available in the Android/Compose API to address this issue as this seems to be a native Android Compose SDK bug.

It sounds like when you click on the compose TextField, then the EditText, the Compose code is losing focus before the EditText gains it. Thus you have a brief time when there is no focused element, so the keyboard closes.  In that case you'll need to move up the time at which the EditText gets focus.  I'd try adding logging in the EditText's onClickListener, onTouchListener, and whatever method is called in Compose (if any) when it loses focus to see the order they occur in.  If the clickListener or touch listener happens first (which I expect), try to manually focus the edittext there.
